# Plotting large data sets in 3d with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, graph

I need to be able to plot lines on three axes with negative as well as positive co-ordinates. (Preferably in WPF)

the dataset consists of (x, y ,z) coordiantes and will have thousands of lines. Each line having hundreds of points.

I need to plot it so that I can join the points to show the line which connects them.

So what's the best way to do this? I have no experience with DirectX or any kind of visualisation software. Is there a good 3rd party library that you would recommend?

This is for a university research project so products which have an academic license or discount would be nice.

I'm hoping I don't have to code this whole graphing software myself as it is not the point of the project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com but it has not been updated for a while.

Comment: Thank you, but this software does not seem to be capable of plotting on 3 axes.

Comment: Check this sample video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahwaBn5CImE. 
Also the latest version is always under Source Code tab not Downloads.

Comment: Very nice, i will give it a try

Comment: Thanks Den, but I went with TeeCharts - its pricey but I can get a discount for academic use.

Answer (score 1):

Possible [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) library (LGPL for core) meet yours requirements. But only C-like interface is available for C#.